# make object disappear in animation

Tags: animation

I animated several objects moving along a certain path. That works well.
Now I wanted to make one of the objects disappear. When I delete the element in
a later keyframe it is removed in all keyframes before. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Just move it out of frame?

Comment: I have looked at the answer of the same question asked previously. But there is a problem. I am using Blender 2.82 and the outliner looks different from what is shown in this answer.  In particular, there is no camera icon behind the word "Camera" only the eye. When I press "i" for insert keyframe, as instructed in the answer, I get the message "no active Keying set".

Comment: Moving the object out of the visible area - if that is what Filip Frank suggests - looks like a workaround. But I will try it.

Comment: I'm not able to check at the moment but one of the icons above the list allows you to activate the "Camera" collumn.

Comment: Found it. After clicking the funnel icon in the place you hinted to,  I could activate the camera column. Thanks Filip!